# Perl in Web Development

Tags: perl, cgi

I have heard a lot about using Perl in web development for CGI scripts but are they still widely used today?  From a development (Not an Administrative) point of view, is it worth learning?  What would be an example of something that is better handled in Perl than PHP?

Thanks

Comment: CGI is still widely used, not only with Perl, but frequently on hostings PHP scripts are run as CGI. Same for other languages.

Answer (score 10):

My answer is that CGI is obsolete and you shouldn’t learn web programming in Perl in combination with CGI. There’s a very nice web framework called [Mojolicious](http://www.mojolicious.org/), that could be a fun way to get started with web programming in Perl. Once you want to deploy your application to a server, you can use [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) to interface between the server and your app. [Dotcloud](http://docs.dotcloud.com/components/perl/) seems to be a promising, hassle-free host for such apps.

As for the PHP vs. Perl question, that’s hard to answer without causing a flamewar. For me, Perl is much more mature and better thought-out ecosystem. Opinions may vary.

Answer (score 10):

Don't bother with CGI in any language (Perl, C, etc) but look at modern web frameworks. And in this area Perl is fully loaded:

- [Dancer](http://perldancer.org)
- [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)
- [Mojolicious](http://www.mojolicious.org/)
- [WebNano](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebNano)

And since they all use PSGI you can deploy them on any server such as FastCGI, Apache/mod_perl, nginx and as legacy CGI scripts. There are also Perl specific application servers like [Starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Starman), [Corona](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Corona), [Tatsumaki](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tatsumaki), etc.

Answer (score 7):

While making subjective predicates here, is not the best idea, I can only argue with some job offer sites (as you can see, than perl still lead):

- [indeed](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=perl,%20ruby,%20python,%20php)
- [simplyhired](http://www.simplyhired.com/a/jobtrends/trend/q-Perl,+Python,+PHP,+Ruby)

At the other side, "CGI" is archaic. Now perl developers use Plack (PSGI) and similar techniques.

Answer (score -2):

I'd venture to say that nothing new is done with Perl/CGI scripts today, but there probably are a good number of legacy sites that are still implemented with Perl/CGI.

From a development point of view, I'd say it's worth spending a day or two learning CGI with Perl (provided you already know Perl). I say this because CGI (Common Gateway Interface) with Perl will expose you to the underpinnings of the web (namely HTTP POST, GET, Request Variables, Server Environment Variables). With Perl/CGI, you get to manipulate these things directly, and that hands-on ability is helpful when dealing with any of today's modern frameworks.