# How do I get started working with Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

Where is a good place to learn how to use CGI with perl for making websites?

I will be running on Linux with apache2, but there is a possibility I may run on Windows for our company. I need to make a site for internal use only, that one might run on Windows with IIS.

Comment: You should mention what operating system you are using, this will help focus answers on more useable solutions for you.  Also, trying searching here or Google for "learn perl cgi"

Comment: CGI as a technology is about as relevant as fax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re not forced into CGI, forget about it – it’s obsolete & sucks. Some alternatives are listed in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939689).

Comment: It is simple but has poor performance. If you don't need much performance, then it doesn't suck, and the simplicity is a boon.

Comment: @Quentin it's not simple; it's an untidy mess of environment variables with odd behaviors and not-quite-HTTP spoken over pipes. There are replacements that are simpler *and* better-performing.

Comment: Not simple, and easy to make huge security mistakes. So please stop using writing CGI directly. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Comment: Wow this question is old. I ended up pretty much dropping this idea and instead decided to stick to shell scripting and other task more for server work.

Answer (score 4):

The CGI module from CPAN is the canonical starting point for basic CGI scripts, and there are a lot of reasons to use it versus handling your own param parsing.  CGI.pm (the module) handles behind the scenes a lot of things that you don't want to have to build yourself.  If you need to maintain state, CGI::Session helps.  And if you plan on expanding beyond simple CGI scripting you can plan larger applications around CGI::Application in combination with a templating solution.

For the output side, Template::Toolkit or HTML::Template are commonly used.

There is the somewhat outdated book, CGI Programming with Perl (O'Reilly).  Though it is outdated it does give a good overview and starting point for basic CGI.  I wouldn't hesitate to recommend purchasing a used copy (there are copies available used online starting for the cost of shipping).  It's definitely worth reading through.  Even though it doesn't address some of the more modern issues such as Unicode, it still lays out for you the start to finish CGI process.  That alone is worth the read.

Perhaps start by reading the POD for CGI, and later for CGI::Session.  Build from there.

There is so much more to the "state of the art" nowadays than simple CGI, but you have to start somewhere.  If your plan is to develop complex sites, beyond what CGI::Application can facilitate, you'll start wondering about Catalyst, Mojolicious, and other frameworks.  But that's a different topic.  The old saying from Economists, "It depends..."  It depends on what you want to accomplish, whether CGI will be a good fit versus a more robust and scalable framework.

Comment: I like your answer, So pretty much I just have to start working with it. Any tutorials or anything I could look at to get a step in the right direction, I am already working with perl.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, forget CGI.

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
cpanm --interactive Task::Plack
```

will run a while (bit long), but will install for you the basics for modern perl/web development - Plack and several middle-wares.

Read step-by-step thru fantastic [Miyagawa's Plack advent calendar](http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-1-getting-plack.html), and after a while you will be an perl/web/app-dev/guru. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Module [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) will fill your CGI needs. As for making web sites, that has nothing to do with CGI, and I don't have a reference handy.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is a good place to learn how to
>   use CGI with perl for making websites?

I suggest a good history book that talks about the "dot-com boom" of the mid to late 90s - that's about the time period when CGI was in common use.

If, on the other hand, you'd like to learn something that's still relevant today, I suggest looking at mod_perl or FastCGI, using a framework such as Catalyst or Plack.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't learn CGI. Learn instead a modern and clean Perl web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/). And if you want to understand the lower levels of the modern Perl 5 stack, read about [PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI).

Comment: I would suggest to still learn it so you het a good understanding of how web works, then learn some other framework/stack

Comment: @texabruce CGI is useless in today's web world. If you want to learn the lower levels of the Perl 5 web stack, learn [PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI), but absolutely not CGI.